# Cakephp pagination with or condition

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to be able to put 'or' condition inside a foreach loop when defining pagination variable at the controller like below:

```
foreach($p as $ps){
$this->paginate = array(
                'or' => array(
                    array('Petition.commune_id LIKE' => $commune_ids['Commune']['id'] . ","),

                    ),Recipe
                'limit' => 10
            );

}
```

I know above is wrong but I've compiled the codes for demonstration purposes. Is there a way we can do this in cake?

I need to loop because I want to be able to use ids from another table (which has been fetched as an array by find method) and use this for looping in the current table which is Petitions table. $commune_ids['Commune']['id'] is what I need to loop through as or value. Alternatively the query will be like:

```
SELECT * FROM petitions WHERE commune_id = 971 OR commune_id = 123 OR commune_id = 321 OR commune_id = 432
```

but of course I can do this in find function but I would like to paginate this results...

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make any sense. Why the loop in the first place?

Comment: I need to loop because I want to be able to use ids from another table (which has been fetched as an array by find method) and use this for looping in the current table which is Petitions table. $commune_ids['Commune']['id'] is what I need to loop through as or value. Alternatively the query will be like: SELECT * FROM `petitions` WHERE `commune_id` = 971 OR `commune_id` = 123 OR `commune_id` = 321 OR `commune_id` = 432
but of course I can do this in find function but I would like to paginate this results...

Comment: If you've got a lot of code or explaining to do, please _please_ don't just bung it in a comment; **edit** the question so we can all benefit from having it nicely formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM petitions WHERE commune_id IN (971, 123, ...)
```

In Cake, that's:

```
'conditions' => array(
    'Petition.commune_id' => array(971, 123, ...)
)
```

So you make an array of ids which you can put into the condition. Done.

```
$communeIds = /* assemble array somehow */;

$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Petition.commune_id' => $communeIds
    ),
    'limit' => 10
);
```

Comment: Don't we just love Cake for making our lives easier?